# what does *map function do in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i saw this code on the internet but i don't know what that starred expression in front of map function do. 
here's the code

```
print(*map(input().find,map(chr,range(97,123))))
```

i was thinking about args but it doesn't apply for this code because this is map function right? does it relate to map function or print function? or both?

also i tried running this code without that star in front map function like this

```
print(map(input().find,map(chr,range(97,123))))
```

but the output was this

```
<map object at 0x7f42409d50f0>
```

Comment: It's just unpacking the result of `map`